# Work when the angle between force and displacement is between 90° and 180°?

Tags: vectors, work

If the angle between *Force* and *Displacement* is obtuse, then by using the formula of *Work* we get a negative quantity. Is it then said that the system is losing energy or it is merely for the case when *Force* and *Displacement* are opposite to each other?

Answer (score 1):

The vertical component of the force doesnt do work, so a force with an obtuse angle can be considered to be oppossed to the diplacement. In any case, whenever work is negative, the system is losing energy.

Comment: And what it will be when angle is greater than 180 degree?

Comment: in between 90 and 270 degrees the force will have a component opossed to the displacement (except at presicely 90 and 270), so the work will be negative and the system is losing energy.